# Firefox A11y audit "Content with images must be labeled" for video element

Tags: html, firefox, accessibility

I'm not sure why, but the FireFox A11y tool is giving me a text label error for my video element. I've tried to add as many labels as I can, and it's not picking any up.

"MY LABEL" is all the same label.

```
<video class="vid desktop" loop playsinline muted preload="none" aria-label="MY LABEL" title="MY LABEL">
  <source src="MY VID URL" type="video/mp4" aria-label="MY LABEL" title="MY LABEL">
  MY LABEL
</video>
```

I'm at a loss of what else I can do to get it to read a label.

Comment: Please could you provide the outputted HTML and the exact error message. [`aria-label` is not well supported on video elements](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/media/video-aria-label/) so I imagine it is asking for something specific.

Comment: I'd rather not paste the resulting code, which would include the URL of the site and video. Just know that get_bloginfo("name") just returns the site title. Everything else is the same. As for the error message, it's "Text Labels and Names Error Content with images must be labelled. "

There is another error that I assume is unrelated: "Keyboard
Error

Clickable elements must be focusable and should have interactive semantics."

Comment: Why can't you remove the urls?  Search and Replace makes it easy.  Shouldn't take more than 1 minute.

Comment: @quantumPuter I guess I just didn't see the need, but I've done it now.